# How to put 2 Frames in 1 Application with wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hello i have created 2 frames, and when I run this program it will show each frame as their own application (at least on windows). Is there a way to use both frames but put them in one application?

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.NewId(), "Main") 
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Open a child")
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)

        self.Layout()

    def on_button(self, evt):
        frame = ChildFrame(self)
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.MakeModal(True)

class ChildFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Child")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

    def on_close(self, evt):
        self.MakeModal(False)
        evt.Skip()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Here is an image of what I do not want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gayc.png

that is what I do not want,
I would like both frames to be in ONE application.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an app that does what you /do/ want? I'm *guessing* it's MDI, but I'm not really confident in that guess.

Comment: (PS: Don't do MDI, nobody likes MDI.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These frames already are running in the same wxPython application (`MyApp`).
Probably what you mean is to have the two frames/windows in the same wxPython window.

I think this is not possible because `wx.Frame` class is by definition an independent window.

What you can do very easily is to modify your current classes to derive from `wx.Panel` instead of from `wx.Frame` and then put the two panels in the same Common Frame.

For example for the ChildFrame you modify like this:

```
class ChildPanel(wx.Panel): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId())
    .........................................
```

Then you create the common Frame and instatiate your panels (and set them in a sizer):

```
class Common(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Common")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

        self.child = ChildPanel(self, .....)
        self.main = MainPanel(self, .....)

        ...................
```

If as suggested in Inerdial's comment you are actually looking for MDI windows:

[image]

Then you have to use the wx.MDIParentFrame and wx.MDIChildFrame's classes. For an example, check the MDIDemo.py example in the [wxPython docs and demos](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable) package. Note that although wxPython supports Multiple Document Inteface windows, Windows has deprecated MDI.

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the "MainFrame" rather than creating a new class

Answer (score 0):

I think putting the style option of the child frame as wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR in the argument while initializing child frame may solve the issue.